# Can we create a web application contain workflow,rues and deploy in alfresco tomcat?

Tags: spring-mvc, alfresco

I am new to Alfresco,i tried sample review and approval document workflow with email alerts success fully completed, now I want to build a web application for same workflow in spring but I need help to how to integrate my workflow with spring application like start workflow and complete, claim tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate your workflow in any java application via the Activiti workflow engine...
Take a look here : http://www.activiti.org/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,i want with any web application not with java application because in java application one class is generating with unit test it is calling our bpmn file same java code i placed in web application but it is showing classnot found of activiti.cfg.xml. this is my java code

Comment: Activiti is for Java application only, i'm afraid !

Comment: please share me any links or reference for java application i will use in spring.thanks in advance